# web3js send transaction failed when contract modify mapping data , but remix work

Tags: web3js, remix, mapping

first, web3 version: `1.0.0-beta.36`

the contract code is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

contract Main {
  struct Model {
    uint256 key;
    uint64 createTime;
  }

  Model[] public models;

  mapping(uint256 => address) public modelOwner;

  function total() view public returns (uint256) {
    return models.length;
  }

  function getData(uint256 _tokenId) view returns ( uint256, uint64){

    Model _model = models[_tokenId];
    return  (_model.key, _model.createTime);
  }

  function createData(uint256 _key, address _owner) returns (uint){

    Model memory _model = Model({key : _key, createTime : uint64(now)});

    uint256 newModelId = models.push(_model) - 1;

    // modelOwner[newModelId] = _owner;

    return newModelId;
  }
}
```

I send transaction by remix and web3.js:

```
myContract.methods.createData(
 key,
 addressA
).send({
 from: addressB 
})
```

the problem is :

1. when I remove the code `modelOwner[newModelId] = _owner;` in function `createData`, web3 and remix both work **(List models increase)**;
2. when I add `modelOwner[newModelId] = _owner;`, remix work, but web3 failed, because the result of the method `getData` returned is not correct **(List models not increase)**;

Comment: One difference between remix and web3.js is that web3 uses a default gas of 90k and remix will estimate the required gas. You can add gas parameter to send, like `.send({ from: "0x....", gas: 1000000 })`.

Comment: @Ismael yes, I forgot the difference, and web3js works after I add the `gas`